# How to use Java stubs generated by wsimport to write a Java client?

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client, wsimport

I need to consume a `Web Service`. They sent me the `WSDL` and `XSD` files. I generated Java stubs using **wsimport**. I am confused because wsimport generated seperate classes for the methods implementations of a class too.
The classes have no implementation of their own other than set and get methods.

How can i use them in my java code to creat a client?
I am relatively new to Web Services.

Kindly help me out here.

Comment: There are so many howtos/examples in the net. What about this one: http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client/

Comment: http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client/

Comment: http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/